# Use forwarded it in a sentence

Tags: meaning, sentence

is this the correct sentence?

```
I have forwarded it to the client.
```

I am sending an email to my boss and i want to tell him that i have sent his email to the client So the above sentence is correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, but it might not sound very aesthetically pleasing, so you can just use "I have forwarded your/the email to the client" instead of using "it".

Answer (score 0):

`I have forwarded it to the client.`

Yes, this is correct.